# Bigcommerce Stencil error

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using `bigcommerce` stencil and have started working on it. But today I got this error:

> {"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}.

Can any body help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer would help.

If you have selected Blueprint theme at Store SetUp --> Design and running Stencil locally. It will throw 500 error.

Try to select any stencil free theme at Store Setup --> Design. And then run the command(stencil start).

It will Work. :)

Comment: I have contacted to Bigcommerce but they said we can not help you in that and contact to Stencil. I have raised a ticket but no response yet.

Comment: @Mitd, let's wait for their response. As, i have also tried the same to check. The same error occurs. I have also created a case at Bigcommerce developer support portal.

Comment: @Mitd, I have just edited an answer. This would help you. :)

Comment: This answer is correct.  You have to have a Stencil theme applied to your store to run the Stencil CLI and startup your local environment (at least to start - you might be able to switch to a blueprint later but Stencil has to be active on the store at some point)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` in the console from your project directory once before running `stencil start` to make sure you have the latest versions of all packages. I've run into this issue in the past when my files get out of sync from working from two computers. This may fix it for you.